# How to calculate the character of this series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\:\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}+1}{\sqrt{n}\left(n+1\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate the character of this series? Can you could show me the steps to to follow? Thank you
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\:\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}+1}{\sqrt{n}\left(n+1\right)}$$

Comment: What is the "character" of a series? Convergence?

Comment: yeah converge or diverge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: The terms behave as 
$$
\frac{n^{1/3}}{n^{3/2}}=\frac1{n^{7/6}}
$$

Comment: so it converges for the comparison with the Harmonic series?

Comment: @Amarildo No. It converges because series $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p>1$. Harmonic series ($p=1$) is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Put $n = x^6$ then the general term of the series is $$\frac {x^2 + 1} {x^3 (x^6 + 1)} = \frac {1} {x^3 (x^4 - x^2 + 1)} \sim \frac {1} {x^7} = \frac {1} {n^{7/6}}$$ by limit comparison test we have that this series converges since $\sum 1/n^p$ converges for every $p > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

here $u_n$=$(n^{1/3}+1)/(\sqrt{n}(n+1))$, let $v_n$=$1/n^{7/6}$ and use limit comparison test so that $\lim u_n/v_n$=$\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+n^{2/3})/(n+1)$=$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n^{1/3})/(1+1/n)=1 \neq 0$ So by limit comparison test both the series behave alike and being a p series with $p>1$ series $v_n$ converges so does the given series.

Remark: for identifying which series to be chosen for comparison one can look at the maximum power to which n is raised in both numerator and denominator and take the difference of that as the power of n in $v_n$.